# Alternate ways to declare arrays in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, types, typescript, tuples

My Typescript file will compile with either of these declarations. Are they equivalent? Is there a name for these ways of declaring arrays?

```
interface Foo {
    bounds: number[][];
    bounds2: [[number, number], [number, number]];
}
```

The library into which I'm passing `bounds` takes an array of two two-element arrays. `bounds2` seems to express that more clearly above, but I'm not sure it's really doing the same thing.

Comment: I would have used `bounds2: Array<Array<number>>`. I'm very interrested as well about the second one :)

Comment: Array vs. tuples : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same thing.

`bounds` represents an array of arrays of `number`s.

`bounds2` represents something that is called a tuple type, which is like a more detailed array description (with types on specified indexes). In this case this is a tuple containing two tuples, which both contain two `number`s

Comment: Thank you! It looks like `bounds2` is far better for this use.

Comment: Yup, general use case for tuples is when you have a short group of same or mixed types with the length know in advance.

Comment: When you refer to tuple, it's not a tuple in a strict mathematics sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code illustrates it quite nicely:

```
let a: number[][];
let b: [[number, number], [number, number]];

a = [5]; // error
a = [[5]]; // ok
a = [[5],[8,9,10]]; // ok
a = [[5],[8,9,10], [5]]; // ok
a = [[5, 'a']]; // error

b = [5]; // error
b = [[5]] // error
b = [[5,5]] // error
b = [[5,5], [5,5]] // ok
b = [[5,5],  [5]] // error
b = [[5,5],  [5,5,5]] // ok, a bit surprisingly
b = [[5,5,5],  [5,5,5]] // ok, a bit surprisingly
b = [[5,5,5],  [5,5,5], [5,5,5]] // ok, a bit surprisingly
b = [[5,5,5],  [5,5,5], [5,5,5, 'a']] // error
b = [[5,5,5],  [5,5,5], [5,5,5], [5,5,5,5,5,5]] // ok, a bit surprisingly 
b = [[5,5,5]] // error
```

Comment: Interesting. So it seems that the declaration says, "this is an array of more than one array of numbers, each of which is at least length 2."

Comment: Yes, TypeScript seems to follow this kind of *less-strict approach* in a few other cases. For example number indexers behave strangely on a first sight.

Comment: Aha - see the last comment here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5259

Comment: Nice catch. Too bad you didn't ask for TS1.6 specifically. I would be right then, since this won't be most likely backported. ;)